# How to query for landscape and portrait image size for mobile?

Tags: optimization, cloudinary

I'm using cloudinary and am wondering how I can optimize an image request for mobile users. I'm going to use the image as a background image for the web application and can request a `fit_w,fit_h/image.jpg` crop to fit perfectly for portrait when the user starts the web app. Although if they decide to turn their phone to landscape, I'm not entirely sure what the best way is to handle the transition.

- I can rotate the fitted portrait image and scale at a loss of quality and possible pixelation
- I can request a larger image that can handle both sizes
- I can make a second request on landscape (which I think is the worst option)

Is there a known practice for handling this sort of situation I may not be aware of? How can I optimize the image for both portrait and landscape?

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice for addressing this subject.
Each method you mention has its pros and cons that you can weigh in and decide what works best for you.

You might find useful our article about [responsive design](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/responsive_images) which might help out.